# How can I include the module with class to another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I have module with class

```
module My < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  format :json

  class Users
    helpers do
      include My2 #I want put here method 'some_method'
    end
  end

end
```

I have another module

```
module My2
  class Circle
    def some_method
      "Hello"
    end
  end
end
```

I can do this, but I wonder how to do with the class

```
module My2
    def some_method
      "Hello"
    end
end
```

I don't understand logical .. Thank you
How can I do it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **include** for including a class, because it uses for including methods from modules in classes.
If you want to use a class, try to pass an instance of class or create class's method.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def baz
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

Foo.bar # => "class method"
Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class

Foo.new.baz # => instance method
Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar’ for #<Foo:0x1e120>
```

[Example](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Comment: Can you tell me. How I can add module which contains class?

Comment: You can use **require** or RoR can do it without you.

Answer (score 0):

I can put

```
def some_method(x, y)
  My2::Circle.new.some_method(x, y)
end
```